# How do I get random element from an Array in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

If I have an array of elements, how do I get a random one from the collection?

For example:

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

# how to get a random value now?
```

Answer (score 2):

Any collection that mixes in the `Indexable` module gains the ability to [`sample`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.0.0/Indexable.html#sample(random=Random::DEFAULT)-instance-method) an element from it. Since an `Array` mixes in `Indexable` you can use the `sample` method for this purpose.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
# 2
a.sample               
# 1
a.sample               
# 5
a.sample(Random.new(4))
```